# Using new (Qt 6.4) QT_ANDROID_SIGN_APK variable

Tags: android, cmake, qt6, release-builds

Did someone tried to use those CMake variables https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/cmake-variable-qt-android-sign-apk.html?

```
QT_ANDROID_SIGN_APK
QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH
QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASS
QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASS
```

With Qt 6.4.2 i tried to declare them as normal variables via set() or as target properties via set_target_properties(), but they have no effect - release build fails with following message:

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1175743032.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1175743032.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]

Answer (score 0):

`QT_ANDROID_SIGN_APK` is a Cmake variable, which can be set from the command-line or via `set()` in a cmake script.

The others are environment variables:
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/tools/androiddeployqt/main.cpp#L621